# fullcalendar populate calendar with events from a database

Tags: javascript, ajax, fullcalendar

I'm trying to use the fullcalendar by Adam Shaw version 2.2.5 to load events from the database but am not sure on how to do it. I've searched but haven't found a solution. I'm using chrome as a browser.

```
`$`('#calendar').fullCalendar({
header: {
    left: 'prev,next',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
},
buttonText: {
    month: 'month',
    week: 'week',
    day: 'day'
},
events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    `$`.getJSON({
        url: "WelcomeModels/Calendar/",
        data: { Status: status, BranchNum: branchNumber, FromDate: fDate, ToDate: tDate, calendarMonth: '12', calendarYear: y },
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            var events = [];
            var obj = data;
            //`$`.map(data, function (me) {
            //    me.title = data['BranchNum'] + ' - BOR - ' + data['Status'], // this is required

                //    me.start = moment(data['ReviewDate']).format();  // this is required

                //    })
                `$`(data).find('event').each(function () {
                    events.push({
                        title: data.BranchNum + ' - BOR - ' + data.Status,
                        start: new Date(data.ReviewDate),
                        backgroundColor: "#0073b7", //Blue
                        borderColor: "#0073b7", //Blue
                        url: 'http://google.com/'
                    });

                });
                callback(events);
            }
        })

    },
```

I expect it to show a calendar with my events but all I get is a calendar with no events.

Comment: I'm using .NET MVC framework to do this. if that helps.

Comment: "all I get is a calendar with no events". Check your browser console for errors. `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` looks like it's in the wrong place, for a start (although, you likely don't actually need it anyway). Secondly $.getJSON doesn't accept all those options - see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/. Those look like the options you'd sent to $.ajax see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/. Those are a couple of obvious mistakes to get you started. Then use your console and network tools to start debugging anything else which raises its head after that

Comment: `success: function (data) {` Are you getting a JSON response or XML response?